# Visual APP to run CMD commands

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I make use of the command prompt quite a bit, but I've noticed that it has really poor support for copying and pasting.

Usually I get around this by creating a batch file, then executing that. What I was wondering is , is there a free program that can execute commands and return the results to a window, I guess if the program had a name it would be something like Visual CMD?

Tired of messing around with batch files, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also redirect the output of most cmd line apps:

[Using Command Redirection Operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Dir /s >C:\AdminInfo\Dir.txt

Above will send the output of the dir command to a text file.

dir /s 2>:\AdminInfo\DirErrors.txt

Above will redirect just the errors to a text file.  Link has more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The default copy/paste functionality in the Windows Command Prompt can be cumbersome.

However, there is a built-in feature called QuickEdit mode.  [Enabling QuickEdit mode](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/249/cmd-copypaste-between-window-and-command-consoledos-program/) can make copying and pasting much simpler.

Basically you can paste with a right-click, and copy with a highlight followed by a right click.  It's nice!